# which strategy is better submitting part of form data in step 1 and rest in step 2 by updating or in a single step?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, oracle, jsp

I want to developing a simple yet fail-proof online registration system using JSP and ORACLE 10g. I want online users to give their basic details in step1 , insert the data, redirect to step 2 , allow the user to enter rest of the details and finally submit the form. But in the second step data will be updating against a serial number which is kept as variable via form hidden field. Such applications are not new, and I am asking how to do it. But my concern is the pros and cons of this strategy. I would also welcome opinions if all data be inserted once into the database rather than in steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To determine better requires criteria for features to be ranked against. You have not provided any other than "simple yet fail-proof". The simplest and most robust method is to use either one or two plain forms with a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with a 2 step approach for user registration.

In the first step, ask the most basic of information like user's name, email, country, etc.

In the second step, you can ask for additional fields like city, address, contact no., twitter handle, etc.

Having a long form broken down into 2 smaller ones has its own advantages. You just need to put up a small registration form that encourages user to sign up.

From the backend perpective, you'll need a service like 'AddUpdateUserDetails'. 
This service can always return userId & status.
When you submit the first form to AddUpdateUserDetails with userId as zero/blank. It creates a new user, makes an entry into the database & returns the newly generated userId.

You can then store this into a invisible form field in the secondary form.
When you submit this form, since the userId is already present, the service will only update the user details in the database & return the same userId in response.